# What do I need to power up an EDF engine?

Tags: model-aircraft, battery

I want to buy a EDF engine (just the engine). What items, such as battery and chargers etc. do i need to buy to power it up?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because specific purchasing advice is not within this site's scope. See [the help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - "...it's not about…    Resource location: Where to buy a specific part"

Comment: but where do i find it then

Comment: Aside from being off-topic, the ancillary equipment you will have to buy will depend on the engine itself.

Comment: @Therac I think the main point of the question is to determine what is required, sources are just a bonus.

Comment: This has no connection at all to purchasing advice (which is like "should I buy a Ford or Chevy?")

Comment: Note that:   *"Resource location: Where to buy a specific part" "*  the question ***utterly does not*** ask "where" to "buy" a "specific" "part".  If the supposed reason for closure is *"Resource location: Where to buy a specific part" "* that is bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An EDF is an electric ducted fan, so I assume you're not interested in the fans powered by internal combustion engines (or actual turbines).

You'll need:

1. an ESC (electronic speed controller) that is rated for at least the maximum current and voltage of the motor in the EDF.
2. a battery that can provide that current and voltage.
3. something to provide a throttle signal to the ESC. Usually this is a transmitter and receiver, but for bench-testing a simple, cheap option is a servo tester.
4. a charger for the battery. This must be able to match the battery chemistry, voltage and capacity (they normally handle a range)
5. if the charger isn't mains powered, it will need a power supply.

There are loads of on-line shops for all this.

Comment: Great answer to a great question.

Comment: Yeah the Q&A really belongs on an RC forum, but great answer nonetheless.